# Failed to open file after many attempts

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I am using PcapDotNet DLL's in my application, and I am encountering a problem:

My application takes a PCap file (Wireshark file) and sends the packets to the network card. If I send a file or files many times (usually ~500 times), my application crashes with the error **Failed opening file C:\file.pcap**. I tried to ask in the project forum, but the developer isn't there permanently, so maybe someone else could help me here.

The error cause is here in **inputCommunicator**, and when the error occurs, this object value is null. Please note that this happens only after a few hundred iterations (approximately 500).

code:

```
    using (PacketCommunicator inputCommunicator = selectedInputDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
    {
        using (mOutputCommunicator = selectedOutputDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
        {                
            while (inputCommunicator.ReceivePacket(out packet) == PacketCommunicatorReceiveResult.Ok && _isStop) //fill the buffer with the packets from the file
            {
                using (PacketSendBuffer mSendBuffer = new PacketSendBuffer((uint)packet.Length * 4))
                {                                                                                       
                    else if (packet != null)
                    {
                        lastTime = packet.Timestamp;
                        mSendBuffer.Enqueue(packet); //put the packet in the buffer
                    }

                    mOutputCommunicator.Transmit(mSendBuffer, _isBurst); //send the packet
                    _numberOfSendPackets++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you accessing the file on disk every iteration?  If so, is there a reason why you are not holding it in memory through the whole process?  is it possible that something else attempts to access the file while your process is running?

Comment: can you show more code.. for example how are you reading the file packet contents..? also are you reading this OffLine..?

Comment: yes, i am accessing the file on disk every iteration and no one attempts to access the file while i am do it and i can holding all the packets in buffer but what should i in case i am want to play different 500 files ?

Comment: Can you please provide more code..? also have you looked at this Link https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Handling%20offline%20dump%20files

Comment: i know this link and i am using the sample of Sending packets using Send Buffer

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in WinPcap.
For the details, see http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-bugs/2012-December/001547.html